# How to set the background of three cells based off of the value in one other cell, relatively?

Tags: excel, vba, background, formula

I'm trying to make a formula that will color code three cells that are directly above/below each other. The color coding depends on the sum of three other cells that are directly above/below each other, and directly across from the cells to be colored.

This part is easy. The rule is:

```
Forumula: =SUM(H5:H7)>30
```

And it applies to:

```
$E$5:$E$7
```

However, the issue is that when I copy the cells that are being colored (E's) to three more cells below them for the next batch, the relative formula does not work as expected. It applies the formula on H6:H8 (+1) instead of H8:H10 (+3).

Is there a way to get the relativeformula to work as expected? I hope this was clear enough. I know it's hard to visual a spreadsheet, but ultimately I need the relative forumla to add +3 instead of +1 when it is copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Problem:**

If I correctly understand, what you are trying to achieve is to have the range `E5:E7` formatted strictly based upon `H5:H7`, then the next three-cell range -  `E8:E10` - based upon `H8:H10` and so on. You can do this by implementing the below solution:

### **Solution:**

**Step 1:** Setup Columns as Below

[image: Excel visual of StackOverflow question of "How to set the background of three cells based off of the value in one other cell, relatively?"]

**Step 2:** Implement Conditional Formatting as Below

[image]

---

### **Explanation:**

I have recreated your issue and I see your problem; it was not that obvious until I played around with changing values of different cells in `Column H`.

Apparently, this has to do with how Excel interprets your instructions (formula) supplied under conditional formatting. To understand this let's first focus on the behavior of cells `E5`, `E6` and `E7` as a function of values in `Column H`.

With the formula `=SUM(H5:H7)>30` did you notice that:

1. `E5` format depends upon `=SUM(H5:H7)`,
2. `E6` format depends upon `=SUM(H6:H8)`, and
3. `E7` format depends upon `=SUM(H7:H9)` and

when you copy the range `E5:E7` three cells down into `E8:E10`, the expected behavior is:

1. `E8` format depends upon `=SUM(H8:H10)`,
2. `E9` format depends upon `=SUM(H9:H11)`, and
3. `E10` format depends upon `=SUM(H10:H12)`

And this is exactly how the range `E8:E10` will behave once the above solution is applied.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to replicate my problem and spelling out a fix.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the SUMIF in Col K. Either I completely misunderstand the concept of what it's doing, or our column letters do not line up. What values should columns I and H be in your example above? Was I literally supposed to add two blank columns as well?

Comment: @Thisisstackoverflow, did you ever figure out the SUMIFS function?

Comment: No I didn't. I understand what SUMIF does, but I don't understand what it is accomplishing here, particularly because of the columns and rows used. Actually, I see your clarification below. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A partial answer to your question has to do with your relative formula - `=SUM(H5:H7)` - under conditional formatting. Using this formula causes **$E$5** to use `=SUM(H5:H7)` to determine its formatting, **$E$6** to use `=SUM(H6:H8)` to determine its formatting, and so on. This ultimately leads to issues with the conditional formatting even before you begin copying the cells down.

**EDIT:** *(piggy-backing off @Bharat Anand's answer)*

@Bharat Anand's answer appears to be the best way to accomplish this question.

@Thisisstackoverflow requested clarification (under the accepted answer) and I'm hoping my screenshot below will help.

I set my worksheet up in what I believe is the exact same manner as @Bharat Anand, and it seems that the column letters may have been off. Setting mine up like this made it work correctly.

[image: Excel visual of StackOverflow question of "How to set the background of three cells based off of the value in one other cell, relatively?"]

**EDIT:** *(clarification for future visitors)*

I really liked @Bharat Anand's solution, so I wanted to explain how it works (using the images/formulas in the solution as reference):

The calculation in **Column I** is setup to return a number that will only appear *three times*, in succession, in **Column I**; in this way it kind of behaves like a unique identifier, allowing other formulas to reference these values for calculation purposes.

*Three times* is key for the original poster because they were looking for a range of *three* cells to be formatted based on a sum of *three* cells. For example, the formula in **Column I** can be modified to

`=ROUNDDOWN((ROW()-b)/a,0)`

where:

`a` is your desired number of cells to format/sum, and

`b` is equal to `a` - 1.

Using the formula in `J5` as an example, this `SUMIF` formula uses `I3:I7`, which includes *two* (or `b`, as setup in my explanation above) rows above and *two* (`b`) rows below to decide if `I5` equals any of the values found in `I3:I7`. It's important to include the *two* rows above and *two* rows below so that the range overlaps the same *three* cells to meet the requested requirements.

When `I5` finds a match, the formula looks to **Column H** to sum those rows in `H3:H7` where `I3:I7` equals `I5`. In this example, `J5`, `J6`, and `J7` will each equal 32.

Using the simple conditional formatting formula that was setup, we know that cells in **Column E** should be highlighted when the corresponding row in **Column H** is greater than 30. According to the original question, this should be done in ranges that are *three* (`a`) rows tall. We already handled for that, so all that was left was to make sure the conditional formatting spanned the data area in **Column E**.

*I'm hoping I don't confuse and/offend anyone with this explanation, but it's how I understand it. I like the proposed solution and explaining it to myself again helps me solidify how it works.*

Comment: So is there a way to fix this other than the workaround provided by Bharat?

Comment: There may be another way, I'm not sure, but I agree with the accepted answer. However, you could always approach the solution by placing your helper columns (I & J in my screenshot above) in columns A & B and hiding them; I've found them to be less likely to be messed up by the user when placed there. You may also want to consider using defined names for the formulas in columns I & J to help clean up the worksheet a bit.

Also, please see my edit above. @Bharat Anand deserves full credit for the answer, but hopefully this screenshot helps clarify the accepted answer.

Comment: You're very welcome! I attempted just now to add clarification (for both future me and future visitors). I hope it doesn't end up confusing you.